# other ways to achieve persistence in java other than MySQL

Tags: java

how would i saver the state of a java program so that if i had to give the copy from the dist folder that it would still work on another computer without for instance the other computer having MySQL installed etc

Comment: Do you mean DB by "state of program"? Then: remote DB, "db" in a file, DB initialization script with `h2 database`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of MySQL, you can use 100% Java relational databases such as [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/), [H2 Database engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or the [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/). Starting at Java 6, the SDK included Derby as [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/faqs-jsp-156714.html#2q1). There is a [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/getstart/getstartderby.pdf) in the [Java DB 10 (JDK 8) documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/).

You can include the `.jar` files in your project and use the databases using a JDBC connection without installing any additional software. Application servers such as Glassfish and JBoss uses, by default, Derby and H2 for the example databases and JMS messages. Usually, administrators change that databases (using a different JDBC URL connection) in production.

---

**Notes on using JavaDb or Derby**

Derby (and JavaDB) can run as a [network server or an embedded one](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/adminguide/cadminapps.html). The *network server* allows connections from multiple users/programs. An *embedded server* only works with the application that starts the engine. Both server types are included in the `.jar` files and you can control them using JDBC and the library API.

- **For a network server**, you must start the server and use a JDBC URL connection like `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbname;create=true` where a port and a database are defined or a connection such as `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:\temp\myDatabase;create=true` with the location of the database. You may check the [Vogella's tutorial for Apache Derby](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheDerby/article.html)

  ```
  // use the Derby JDBC driver
  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();

  // connect to the database
  Connection connect = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost/c:/temp/db/FAQ/db");

  // execute a Query
  PreparedStatement statement = connect
              .prepareStatement("SELECT * from USERS");
  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
         :
  ```
- **For a embedded server**, you must use a different JDBC driver and URL. The Connection URL is like `jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true`, and does not include a port. There is an explanation in the [Derby's documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html).

  ```
  // use the Embedded Derby JDBC driver
  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();

  // connect to the database
  Connection connect = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:derby:MyDBTest;create=true");

  // execute a Query
  PreparedStatement statement = connect
              .prepareStatement("SELECT * from USERS");
  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
         :
  ```

Comment: thank you very much i will look into that

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
If there is no very complicated data like you would save it in a table of a database, you could use for example a simple ***config file***.

**Method 2:**
Otherwise you could just use a ***sqllite database***. That's like a database in a single file, that doesn't need a server to run.

**Method 3:**
You could use a ***remote database***. You would have access to the data from anywhere. (Even without copying the Application every time)

**Method 4:**
Use a "Java" database, like for example H2.

***Method ...: There are many other things you can do, to achieve this!***

Comment: thank you for ideas going to have a look and probably try a few and see what suits better